# Xsd with nonlatin elements to java

Tags: java, xsd, xjc

I have an xsd where elements are named with nonlatin chars. How can I  generate java classes, where filelds will be named properly, without "strange" chars: may be I can provide my own rules for per char tranformation?

Comment: Do the characters at least satisfy `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(char)` and `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(char)`?  Could you set the compiler encoding as UTF-8 and just accept these strings?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is through [custom bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) - class and property more specifically. I am not aware of binding customizations at the character level. To implement this as a global, pattern based replacement you would most likely have to write your own plugin and enable extensions in xjc.